# relate textbox text to combobox selected values using dataset in xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, c#-4.0

I am a .net beginner. I populated a combobox (`cmbBrand`) based on selection of value in another combobox (`cmbProduct`). Now i need to show the text in `txtUpdatePrice` TextBox related to the selection of value in `cmbBrand` combobox.

[**Here is my XML file**](http://ideone.com/OnpgJ)

Well till now i wrote the below code:

```
        cmbProduct --> combobox    ---> "productname" tag from xml
        cmbBrand   --> combobox    ---> "brandname" tag from xml
        txtNewPrice--> TextBox     ---> "price" tag from xml
```

**Global**

```
        DataSet dsUpdate = new DataSet();
```

**Form_load**

```
        dsUpdate.ReadXml(@"...\..\stock.xml");
        cmbProduct.DataSource = dsUpdate.Tables[0]
            .DefaultView.ToTable(true, "productname");
        cmbProduct.DisplayMember = "productname";
        cmbProduct.SelectedIndex = 0;
        cmbProduct_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
        cmbProduct.SelectedIndexChanged+=new EventHandler(cmbProduct_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

**cmbProduct_SelectedIndexChanged**  (*Firing event Manually from form load*)

```
        cmbBrand.Items.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow Row in dsUpdate.Tables[0].Select("productname='" + cmbProduct.Text + "'"))
        {
            cmbBrand.Items.Add(Row["brandname"].ToString());
        } 
        cmbBrand.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Just like the above code i want to show text in `txtUpdatePrice` textbox("price" tag from xml) when combobox `cmbBrand` is selected. I dont know how to start to show text in `txtUpdatePrice`. I tried implementing the above same function but no use.

Please help

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just add SelectedIndexChanged for cmbBrand:

**cmbBrand_SelectedIndexChanged**

```
txtUpdatePrice.Text = cmbBrand.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Comment: Actually, `txtUpdatePrice.Text` should have the `price` tag text from xml file in it based on the selection of `cmbBrand` text. How to do this?